# By using matrix method for solving system of equation, how to know whether equation has infinite or no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When we use matrix method to solve system of linear equations, if $|A|= 0$
and $(adjA)B=0$ as well then the system can have either infinite solutions or no solutions at all.

So, how can we know whether it has infinite solutions or not just by using matrix method.

Comment: There will be infinite solutions if $b \in Col(A)$ and no solutions if $b \notin Col(A)$.

Comment: The most efficient way is to augment $b$ with $A$ and apply Gauss-Jordan reduction to $[A | b ]$.  There will be no solution if there is a row of zeros ending with a $1$ in the last column.  Otherwise, there will be infinite solutions.

Comment: @HosamH thanks for replying but I don't have to study Gauss Jordan method. We only have matrix method (as my books says). In that case is the only way is to use coefficient of given equations?

Comment: What does "matrix method" mean ?  can you give me an example of this method ?

Comment: @HosamH in this method we make 3 matrices, $A,X and B$. A matrix have coefficient of the given equations as its elements(each column have coefficient of same variable from different equations). X matrix have all variables written in a single column and B matrix have the constants as its elements written in a column as well. We can say that $A.X=B$. If $A^{-1}$ exists we can say $X=A^{-1} .B$ and system have unique solutions. If |A|=0 then we have 2 cases and if $adj(A)B=O$ we have either infinite solutions or no solution. I was confused how to know whether we have infinite solution case or not

Comment: The only method that I know, is the one that uses Gauss-Jordan elimination of  the augmented matrix of the system, as I mentioned in my previous comment.